# 'fast-forward' vs 'forced-update' for 'git fetch' command

Tags: git, gitpython, git-fetch

I have a python application which maintains a mirror of a git repo by periodically (every 10 seconds) doing `git fetch -v` followed by `git reset --hard` (using `GitPython` library) on that repo. More specifically it uses the following python code to do this

```
Popen(['git', 'fetch', '-v', 'origin'], cwd=absolute_path_to_repo, universal_newlines=True, shell=None)
Popen(['git', 'reset', '--hard', 'origin/branch'], cwd=absolute_path_to_repo, universal_newlines=False, shell=None)
```

I was just exploring git logs (inside `.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/<branch_name>` of that repo), and saw 2 different kind of log lines.

```
remotes/origin/{branch-name}:a6aac37 ca8ab94 Application Server Pseudo-User <app@{hostname}> 1547575486 +0000   fetch -v origin: fast-forward
remotes/origin/{branch-name}:6b92d4f a6aac37 Application Server Pseudo-User <app@{hostname}> 1548703807 +0000   fetch -v origin: forced-update
```

The first log line says `fetch -v origin: fast-forward` and the second log line says  `fetch -v origin: forced-update`. I am trying to understand why does git log them differently when they are output of the same command - specially given the fact that the python application is not making any changes in the git repo (its read-only).

The reason why I trying to answer this question is because in `forced-update` case I see that the `HEAD` of my repo moves to an older commit (`a6aac37` corresponds to a month old commit). In all other cases the `HEAD` points to the latest commit.

Another observation was that although `forced-update` rarely happens but happens only at the time there was a push made to the remote. I have verified that those commits were pretty normal (like any other commits).

Comment: Someone with push rights did something to the remote?

Comment: Yeah these things happen exactly at the time when there was a new commit push. But those commits were pretty normal - just like any other commit.

Comment: The duplicate that I'm going to use is actually a different question, about *merging*, but the answer contains everything you need to know about fast-forward vs non-fast-forward in fetch.